# Який правильний український відповідник російського "запаздывающие нейтроны"?

Tags: переклад, терміни, from-russian

«[Запаздывающие нейтроны](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delayed_neutron)» - є продуктом реакції поділу, але з'являються не одразу, а з деяким запізненням після основного поділу.

Ми в КПІ називаємо - *запізнілі нейтрони*.

Але чи правильно так їх називати?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Російський термін «запаздывающие нейтроны» є калькою з англійської [Delayed neutron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delayed_neutron). Тому нема лінгвістичних причин вважати це русизмом.

З точки зору суто-лексичної, *запізнілий* виглядає як доречний переклад терміну “delayed”.

В інших галузях також використовують термін «відкладений» або «відтермінований», напр., “delayed flight” — «відкладений рейс» (літака), «відтермінована зустріч».

З іншого боку, термін *запізнілі нейтрони* широко вживається у сучасній науковій літературі:

> ***Запізнілі нейтрони***, що випромінюються атомними ядрами – осколками поділу ядра урану-235 – зі значним спізненням стосовно моменту поділу — [Розвиток атомної енергетики та об’єднаних енергосистем](http://energetika.in.ua/ua/books/book-4/part-1/section-2/2-1)

…і тому заміна його на інший вираз може призвести до непорозуміння.

Запропонований у коментарях варіант *«кволі» нейтрони* не виглядає слушним внаслідок можливої плутанини з терміном [*повільні нейтрони*](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%96_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8).